# Add Column to table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Is it possible to add a column to an existing table like this:

```
<table id="tutorial" width="600" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

with js?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can do like this

```
 $('#tutorial').find('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').eq(n).after('<td>new cell added</td>');
   });
```

n can be replaced by the number after which column you want to add new column

Comment: and to add the header, if you use it:
`$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
 $(this).find('th').eq(-1).after('<th>HEADER</th>');
 $(this).find('td').eq(-1).after('<td>ROW</td>');
});`

Answer (score 26):

You can use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append a new `td` to the rows

```
$('#tutorial tr').append('<td>new</td>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SP2gh/)

Comment: Or use prepend() to add a cell at the beginning of each row.

Answer (score 3):

You mean column not row?

```
$('#tutorial tr').each(function()
{
    $(this).append('<td></td>');
});
```

Which selects the `<tr>` element inside id "tutorial" (that is your table is this case) and append new contents behind its original contents

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option to those above is to create the column together with the other and a style of `display:none;` and then using the `method .Show()` to display.